# How does `double_wave.py` (custom shape feature from Locust) work?

Tags: python, shapes, locust

I am trying to understand the math behind the following custom shape code: [double_wave.py](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/custom_shape/double_wave.py)

The important piece of code is this:

```
min_users = 20
peak_one_users = 60
peak_two_users = 40
time_limit = 600

def tick(self):
    run_time = round(self.get_run_time())

    if run_time < self.time_limit:
        user_count = (
            (self.peak_one_users - self.min_users)
            * math.e ** -(((run_time / (self.time_limit / 10 * 2 / 3)) - 5) ** 2)
            + (self.peak_two_users - self.min_users)
            * math.e ** -(((run_time / (self.time_limit / 10 * 2 / 3)) - 10) ** 2)
            + self.min_users
        )
        return (round(user_count), round(user_count))
    else:
        return None
```

I know that they are setting a minimum amount of users and somehow generating two peaks. However, the function is not clear for me. I would like to understand where they come from so I can play around and adjust it for my needs.

Basically, I would like to know:

1. Is this some known equation with specific parameters?
2. Is it possible to determine when each peak should occur?
3. What is necessary in order to have this kind of behavior for other `time_limit` values?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Locust docs](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/generating-custom-load-shape.html):

> In this class you define a tick() method that returns a tuple with the desired user count and spawn rate (or None to stop the test). Locust will call the tick() method approximately once per second.

The feature works by allowing you to programmatically set the users and spawn rate. You can make `tick()` return whatever you want. The example is just making a wave form in the graph. Whatever math you want to use will work, just `return user_count, _spawn_rate` with whatever values you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if they have sourced this equation from somewhere or written themselves but things can get clear if you see from mathematical function perspective.

Consider the function `f(t)` for `number of users(y axis)` with `time(on x axis)`, with other constants like `p1` (peak1), `p2` (peak2), `T` (total time limit) and `m` (min users). If you try to put `t = T/3` then `f(T/3) -> p1` and `f(2T/3) -> p2`, so your two peaks are distributed uniformly over T period.